# Reading format in Fortran 90

Tags: format, fortran

I have a huge file to read whose structure is:

```
 [...]
 (0,0,0,0,0): 5.00634e-33, 5.59393e-33, 6.24691e-33, 7.29338e-33,
 (0,0,0,0,4): 7.77607e-33, 8.95879e-33, 9.65316e-33, 1.07434e-32,
 (0,0,0,0,8): 1.20824e-32, 1.34983e-32, 1.49877e-32, 1.73061e-32,
 (0,0,0,0,12): 1.919e-32, 2.15391e-32, 2.3996e-32, 2.67899e-32,
 [...]
```

I'm interested in reading the value after ":", which `format` should I use in the read statement if I use Fortran90?

I've tried with

```
 read(1,'("(",I6,",",I6,",",I6,",",I6,",",I6,"):",F10.4,F10.4,F10.4,F10.4)')idx1,idx2,idx3,idx4,idx5,dummy1,dummy2,dummy3,dummy4
```

But I got a `forrtl: severe (64): input conversion error`

Comment: Besides the solution of M.S.B. you can read the whole line into a string, replace any `(`, `)` and `:` with space and then read from the resulting string using list-directed IO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since it appears that the items don't line up in columns this is tricky to do with formats.  I'd approach it this way:

```
read (55, '(A)')  string
colon_pos = index (string, ":")
read (string (colon_pos+1:len_string), * ) real1, real2, real3, real4
```

read each line into a string, locate the colon, then use list-directed IO to process the numeric values in the string after the colon.